# Getting SQLFetch Return Code 1004 (Right Truncation) on a query with no parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, cobol

Someone at my client's company is accessing my SQL-Server Express 2012 via ODBC

Their code is in COBOL which i don't have access to.  However he's stating that if he runs the following query, SQLFetch is returning the first few records then getting a right truncation error on my database:

```
SELECT        labCodes.labCode, labCodes.description, labCodes.price, labCodes_localPrices.localPrice
FROM            labCodes LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     labCodes_localPrices ON labCodes.labCode = labCodes_localPrices.labCode
```

The labCodes.description field is the only string field (it's varchar(80)) so I asked him to try LEFT(labCodes.description,10) and that ran fine, he experimented and found that if he sets it to LEFT(labCodes.description,62) the program will run fine but at len of 63 it dies still.  There are quite a few records that are the near the complete 80 characters so this is non-optimal.

Since there is no where clause I don't understand how he's getting a truncation error at all.

Thanks

Edit to Add code from the cobol guy re: @bohica 's comment
Buffers are 80 characters.

```
01 Sql-Data.
        03 q-Col                       PIC X(80) OCCURS 50.
```

And I am binding with SQL-C-Char.

```
PERFORM VARYING Perf-Count FROM 1 BY 1
             UNTIL Perf-Count > Num-Cols
             CALL ODBCAPI "SQLBindCol"
             USING BY VALUE hstmt
                   BY VALUE Perf-Count
                   BY VALUE SQL-C-CHAR SIZE 2
                   BY REFERENCE q-col(Perf-Count),
                   BY VALUE cbValueMax,
                   BY REFERENCE pcbValue
         IF Return-Code <> SQL-Success
           DISPLAY "SQLBindCol: " Return-Code
           PERFORM Get-Sql-Error
           MOVE Num-Cols TO Perf-Count
 END-IF
END-PERFORM
```

*2nd Edit:

**I tried changing the varchar(80) to char(80) and that had no effect.**

I finally got the actual error message he's getting from his COBOL app so here's that:

```
 * Accepted - CONFIRM
 SQLFetch: +0001
 SQLerror: +0000
 SQL-STATE is: 01004
 Message : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation
 SQLExecDirect: -0001
 SQLerror: +0000
 SQL-STATE is: 24000
 Message : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
```

**3rd and final edit**

I got a copy of the COBOL code and noticed that the value of cbVALUEMax was being set to 63 during execution.

Comment: Not sure if it's your issue...haven't worked with a cobol programmer in over 15 years, but from what I remember...the language is expecting to see 80 chars for a field.  If the field isn't 80chars, you get this issue.  Try padding out the field with spaces so it's 80 chars and not varying lengths for each row.

Comment: @Twelfth  Thank you for the reply, I suggested this to him and he said that the error was coming from the SQL server and not his code so he's skeptical.

Comment: How does the same query work in SSMS?

Comment: Assuming the SQL script runs fine on the server for you but not in his code, I'd suspect his code.  I'm curious what select min(len(description) from...  returns...if it's 62, you know the issue...if not, it's something else.  (Complete side note, but I've never seen anyone use cobol to get data out of MSSQL...I've seen it used to load a MSSQL server as we migrated away from the old system, but never the other way around.  This rates with one of the more odd SQL questions I've ever seen on Stackoverflow for that reason)

Comment: @Andrew 1  it returns fine in ssms and from my c# app.

Comment: @Twelfth the min on the field is 16, and i agree this is insane.

Comment: Another possibility...MSSQL is capable of accepting a character that COBOL can't, and that char is in the 63 position in that varchar record for one of your strings.  Use a substring function to select the distinct list of chars in the 63 spot of that varchar(80) field and see if there's a char in there thats outside of the normal a-z 0-9.

Comment: @Twelfth ooh..  this has possibilities.  I'll check this in the morning when i get back in.

Comment: @SafetyOtter, I don't know.  That error is coming from SQL Server, not Cobol.  SQL Server is throwing it.

Comment: @Andrew well, the difference between his app and mine is that in cobol he has to make direct odbc commands and manage his cursors and stuff that System.Data does automatically for me.   i think the error might be in something he's doing with his odbc code, I'll try and get him to give me his odbc calls in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help if you showed is the exact error text. Assuming the client end is using ODBC API and has issued a SQLFetch then the error returned by the SQL Server driver is Data Truncated then that implies the client end code has passed too small a buffer to retrieve that column value. e.g., It calls SQLBindCol for column 2 saying the buffer length is 62 and not 80 or he's binding not as SQL_C_CHAR.

Comment: I edited the question to show his odbc call, it's just giving response 1004 , I got the right truncation from the docs.

Comment: This was indeed the issue.  He was confusing the size of his var in COBOL with the Column binding buffer length.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm answering this from the COBOL aspect, and that being IBM Mainframe COBOL. If this does not work, what will be key is finding out which COBOL compiler is being used, and finding out how that particular dialect of COBOL represents VARCHARs from your database.

COBOL does not have variable-length strings. COBOL does not have null-terminated strings. There is no bit-pattern that COBOL cannot process, despite an earlier suggestion.

What you need to do is to find how your database/SQL presents a VARCHAR. DB2 on the IBM Mainframe does it like this:

```
01  data-name.
    05  data-name-length  BINARY  PIC 9(4).
    05  data-name-max-data        PIC X(80).
```

I'll take a wild stab and say that your un-named COBOL is the same. If you find the name of the compiler and search for some documentation, you'll probably be able to confirm or deny this.

A better way to define the above is like this:

```
01  data-name.
    05  data-name-length  BINARY  PIC 9(4).
    05  data-name-data.
        10  FILLER OCCURS 1 TO 80 TIMES
            DEPENDING ON data-name-length.
            15  FILLER            PIC X.
```

But the COBOL you are using already has the data in a table. That table will need to include the two-byte binary length, as well as the maximum length for the data.

The MOVE the length from the table to the immediately above length, MOVE the data from the table to the above data-name-data.

Using data-name-data will then give you the entire amount of data, nothing more, nothing less.

Just a note on the BINARY. For an 80-character VARCHAR it will make no difference, but for a VARCHAR greater than 9,999 bytes you will need to ensure that a "native binary" definition is used for the field. For Enterprise COBOL on the Mainframe that is COMP-5. The same for GNU-COBOL/OpenCOBOL. For other dialects it may be different.

Comment: i believe it's an older microfocus compiler.     I'll pass your suggestions on to my client.  thank you